# How to combine two django model objects values in a single queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I need a queryset which should be combination of two model objects.
Please look the code

`models.py`

```
class BudgetSubcategory(models.Model):
    sub_category = models.CharField(
        _("Sub Category"), max_length=255, default=False)
    sub_budget = models.DecimalField(
        _("Budget"), max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal('0.0000'))

class BudgetActivity(models.Model):
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(BudgetSubcategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    activity = models.CharField(
        _("Activity"), max_length=255, default=False)
    cost = models.DecimalField(
        _("Cost"), max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal('0.0000'))
```

in views I'm calling

```
qs1 = BudgetActivity.objects.values('activity').annotate(budget_cost=Sum('cost'))
qs2 = BudgetSubcategory.objects.values('sub_category').annotate(
      actual_cost=Sum('sub_budget'))
```

q1 will be

```
[{'activity': 'activity1', 'budget_cost': Decimal('300.00')},
 {'activity': 'activity2', 'budget_cost': Decimal('2000.00')}]
```

q2 will be

```
[{'sub_category': 'sub_category1', 'actual_cost': Decimal('500.00')}, 
{'sub_category': 'sub_category2', 'actual_cost': Decimal('2300.00')}]
```

But what I need is

```
[{'sub_category': 'sub_category1', 'actual_cost': Decimal('500.00'),
 'budget_cost': Decimal('300.00')}, {'sub_category': 'sub_category2',
 'actual_cost': Decimal('2300.00'),'budget_cost': Decimal('2000.00')}]
```

Please Help me regarding this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an annotation on a related object by using double underscores (`__`):

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

qs2 = BudgetSubcategory.objects.values(
    'sub_category'
).annotate(
    actual_cost=F('sub_budget'),
    budget_cost=Sum('budgetactivity__cost')
)
```

It however might be better to annotate the `BudgetSubcategory` *without* using `.values(..)`, since then you still work with `BugetSubcategory`s, and thus you still have the "logic" that is encapsulated in the model:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

qs2 = BudgetSubcategory.objects.annotate(
    actual_cost=F('sub_budget'),
    budget_cost=Sum('budgetactivity__cost')
)
```